# The file '/SFPageService/6665FFF2-6B04-481C-B4E5-1339DA707C2D_39_Basic.aspx' does not exist

Tags: asp.net, sitefinity-4

We're having a problem with a Sitefinity 4.x deployment on Windows Server 2008 R2.

When we browse to the site we get a 404 error not found, even if we direct the browser directly to the /home file.

We've made sure that the app_data folder has the correct permissions.

We don't know what else could be wrong. It works perfectly on our internal staging environment though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We managed to resolve this issue by removing the precompile option in Asp.net.